# i have issue in shared prefrence

Tags: flutter, dart

Get value

```
Future<void> access() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final TOKEN = prefs.getString("TOKEN");``
    final UserId = prefs.getString("UserId");

    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 2),
            () async =>
        {
          if(TOKEN == null && UserId == null){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DoctorLogin()),
            )
          } else{
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            )
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

Set value

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   final TOKEN = prefs.setString("TOKEN", accessToken!);
   prefs.setString("UserId", mobileNumberController.text);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh9fR.jpg)

Comment: remove async and await from initState

Comment: its not working bro

Comment: Can you show your initState function as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your `prefs.getString` and `prefs.setString` calls are async calls and will move on without actually getting or setting the value (they return a `Future`). You should use `await` with these calls, and if that is not possible (e.g. in `initState`) then you need to wait for those futures to complete elsewhere *before* using the value.

If you don't do this, it is entirely possible that `getString` will return nothing even if it is called after `setString`.